# Selecting all the rows if where condition is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to select all the rows from a temp table when I don't provide any parameters in the `where` clause.

Below is my stored procedure; `#ContactAddressDetails` is my temp table where final data is available. `@ZipCodeOrigin`, `@ZipCodeDestination` are the parameters

- if `@ZipCodeOrigin = null` and `@ZipCodeDestination = null` then I want to get all the records, otherwise only those matching the `where` clause

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [CR2].[spGetEmailAddressByZipsTypeahead]       
     @LoggedInUserId BIGINT
     ,@ZipCodeOrigin VARCHAR(10) = NULL      
     ,@ZipCodeDestination VARCHAR(10) = NULL    
     ,@searchText varchar(15)    
AS      
BEGIN      
    DECLARE @OfficeId INT, @AccountId INT      

    CREATE TABLE #ContactGroupList (ContactGroupId INT)      

    SELECT      
        @OfficeId = OfficeId,      
        @AccountId = AccountID      
    FROM CR2.vwAcgUserCustomer WITH (NOLOCK)      
    WHERE UserID = @LoggedInUserId      

    -- Find the all Contact Group associated to the User, his/her Office and Account      
    INSERT INTO #ContactGroupList      
        SELECT ContactGroupId      
        FROM CR2.ContactGroup WITH (NOLOCK)      
        WHERE ((OwnerType = 1 AND OwnerId = @AccountId)      
               OR (OwnerType = 2 AND OwnerId = @OfficeId)      
               OR (OwnerType = 3 AND OwnerId = @LoggedInUserId))      

    --Display all the addresses of the above contact groups.      
    SELECT       
        CA.ContactAddressId,          
        CA.Email AS [Email],      
        CA.AddressType,      
        CA.AddressCode  
    INTO  
        #ContactAddressDetails      
    FROM 
        CR2.ContactAddress AS CA WITH (NOLOCK)      
    INNER JOIN 
        #ContactGroupList list ON list.ContactGroupId = CA.ContactGroupId      
    LEFT JOIN 
        CR2.ContactAddressDefaultSettings AS CADS WITH (NOLOCK) ON CADS.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId      
    LEFT JOIN 
        CR2.ContactAddressDefault CAD WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAD.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId       
                                                    AND CAD.UserId = @LoggedInUserId         
    WHERE 
        CA.ZipCode In  (@ZipCodeOrigin, @ZipCodeDestination)    
        AND CA.Email LIKE @searchText + '%'      
        AND CA.IsDeleted = 0      
        AND CA.AddressType = 3      

    SELECT *      
    FROM #ContactAddressDetails    

    DROP TABLE #ContactAddressDetails      
    DROP TABLE #ContactGroupList      
END
```

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
WHERE CA.ZipCode IN (@ZipCodeOrigin, @ZipCodeDestination)
```

with

```
WHERE (CA.ZipCode In  (@ZipCodeOrigin, @ZipCodeDestination))
   OR (@ZipCodeOrigin IS NULL AND @ZipCodeDestination IS NULL)
```

This condition will be true when both `@ZipCodeOrigin` and `@ZipCodeDestination` are null, or when `CA.ZipCode` matches one or both of them.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this predicate to not filter data if both zipcode are null:

`( (@ZipCodeOrigin is null and @ZipCodeDestination is null) 
  OR CA.ZipCode In  (@ZipCodeOrigin, @ZipCodeDestination)
 )`